# Connection Problems in SSIS using BIML and C#

Tags: c#, ssis, metadata, connection-string, biml

I have a problem with the Connection to an *OleDBSource* in *SSIS* using *BIML*. I want to Import my MetaData table to my *BIML*-Script to generate a *Dynamic Staging Process*. Therefore I need to Import my MetaData table. My goal is to use foreach-slopes to create my Tables/Columns in dependence of my MetaData Table.

Here **My Code**:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.OleDb" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ template language="C#" tier="2" #>

<# var metadataConnectionString = 
"Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=SQLOLEDB;Server=./MSSQL17;Initial 
Catalog=BIMLMetaDaten;Integrated Security=SSPI;"; #>

<# var metadataSelect = @"SELECT * FROM MetaTable";
DataTable dt = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(metadataConnectionString, 
"metadataSelect");
#>

<Connections>
<Connection Name="META" ConnectionString="
<#=logConnectionString 
#>" CreateInProject="true" />
</Connections>


<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Packages>

</Packages>
</Biml>
```

It throws me following **error**:

**[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or no permission.**

It seems a bit weird to me because in all other cases when I used this *ConnectionString* the Connection is usable.

Do you have any suggestions how to get rid of this Error?

Best regards and thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure about that `Server` value in the connection string? I would expect something like `localhost\MSSQL17` assuming `MSSQL17` is the instance name.

Comment: Yes, It's like ServerName/Instance and I'm working on a different machine. But I tried 'localhost' as well but in the end same error.